# Remove xml element with javascript in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How we can remove a xml node in javascript in asp.net C#?

i tried this but is given me an error...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1,this.GetType(),"RemoveDock",
                string.Format(@"function _removeDock()
                                {                                        
                                    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('c:\teste\Config.xml');
                                    x= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Object');                                    
                                    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                                    {
                                        if(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == '{0}')
                                        {
                                            xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(x[i]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                };", HiddenField1.ClientID),true);
```

My xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Form NrForm="Value" State="Value">
  <Object Type="TextBox">
    <ObjectNr>texto valor</ObjectNr>
    <Type>TextBox</Type>
    <Id>RadDocka47ebc1f-848a-4bef-8f31-bc680d776564</Id>
    <x1>Text Label</x1>
    <x2>35</x2>
    <x3>Text</x3>
    <x4>Text</x4>
  </Object>
  <Object Type="TextBox">
    <ObjectNr>texto valor</ObjectNr>
    <Type>TextBox</Type>
    <Id>RadDocka47ebc1f-848a-4bef-8f31-bc680d776564</Id>
    <x1>Text Label</x1>
    <x2>35</x2>
    <x3>Text</x3>
    <x4>Text</x4>
  </Object>
</Form>
```

and i want to eliminate one of this

```
<Object Type="TextBox">
        <ObjectNr>texto valor</ObjectNr>
        <Type>TextBox</Type>
        <Id>RadDocka47ebc1f-848a-4bef-8f31-bc680d776564</Id>
        <x1>Text Label</x1>
        <x2>35</x2>
        <x3>Text</x3>
        <x4>Text</x4>
</Object>
```

Comment: And the error you are getting is...?

Comment: The last Error was that i have Invalid caracters in the statement because it was missing the loadXMLDoc function that can be found in w3schools site

Comment: You would need to double the backslashes in the string literal to include them in a path; otherwise `\t` is a tab character in JS. However, there shouldn't be backslashes in the argument to `loadXMLDoc` at all, because it takes a URL, not a Windows pathname.

Answer (score 2):

```
x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

The first childNode of an `<Object>` is a Text node. Its `nodeValue` will be a bunch of whitespace: the `"\n        "` leading up to the first element child (`<ObjectNr>`).

If you are looking for the text inside the first `<ObjectNr>` node, better say:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName('ObjectNr').firstChild.data
```

assuming there's always one text node inside that element. If you have to cater for it maybe having no text or containing other content than plain text you'd have to write a little function to walk the contents getting text (since MSXML doesn't support the DOM Level 3 Core `textContent` property).

Comment: Thanks! I have changed that but it stills giving me errors, now from another thing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to iterate over the Xml elements in reverse order (last element to first element).

Answer (score 0):

I have one other error... 
I tried a diferent aproach and do this..
found it in..
http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_loadxmldoc.asp

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
            alert("0");
            var xhttp;
            var url = 'c:\teste\Config.xml';
            var hiden1 = document.getElementById('HiddenField');
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open('GET', url, true, "", "");
                xhttp.send('');
                alert("1");
                xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

                x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Object');
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    if (x[i].getElementsByTagName('Id').firstChild.data == hiden1.value) {
                        xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(x[i]);
                    }
                }
                return xhttp.responseXML;
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {          
                alert("2");
            }
            else {
                alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
            }
        }
    </script>


void dock_Command(object sender, DockCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Command.Name == "Close")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                UpdatePanel1,
                this.GetType(),
                "RemoveDock",
                string.Format(@"function _removeDock() {{
    Sys.Application.remove_load(_removeDock);
    $find('{0}').undock();
    $get('{1}').appendChild($get('{0}'));
    $find('{0}').doPostBack('DockPositionChanged');
    loadXMLDoc();    
}};
Sys.Application.add_load(_removeDock);", ((RadDock)sender).ClientID, UpdatePanel1.ClientID),
                true);
            }
        }
```

Now it do the alert (0) but then it gives "Invalid Argument".

The last Error was that i have Invalid caracters in the statement because it was missing the loadXMLDoc function that can be found in w3schools site